# Store home partition on and authenticate users with central server?

Tags: networking

I am planning to roll out a handful of Ubuntu workstations. We have a Debian (samba) fileserver.

I would like to offer a hot-desk situation whereby users could go to any of these ubuntu machines, log on with their username, and pickup their desktop environment.

The server is not high spec; I want programs to run on the desktops, not virtualised on the server or anything like that.

Is this a straight forward thing to do? What technologies or options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

I could mount `/home` on the server (samba or nfs). I could write a script to sync all users in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` with (say) uid>2000 with a list from the server. Then people would be able to log in (their local machine would have their credentials), and their `$HOME` would be on the server.

Crude, but perhaps it could work?

Comment: Can you help with the script to sync all the users in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`  ??